# How to insert a line break in the table header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I tried adding a transition as many advise using < br/>. This works fine until i go into edit mode. Column names display < br/>.

[image]

I also tried setting the property column.PropertiesEdit.EncodeHtml = false;
and put the transition "\r\n" in the name, but this does not work, the line does not wrap.

I also tried to create a transition using CustomColumnDisplayText, but I don’t even get into this method when rendering the page.

```
settings.CustomColumnDisplayText = (s, e) =>
{
   e.DisplayText = e.Value.ToString().Replace(" ", "\r\n");
};
```

I don’t understand what I’m doing wrong, please help me with a seemingly simple problem that I can’t solve for 2 hours already ...

UPDATE:
I add the column as follows:

```
var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "HoodGridView";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "DesignTech", Action = "HoodGridViewPartial" };
    ...

    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Width";
        column.Caption = "Ширина<br/>вытяжки";
        column.PropertiesEdit.EncodeHtml = false;

    });
    ...
}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Comment: How are you adding it exactly?

Comment: @JerdineSabio, I supplemented my question with an example of how I do it.